# Formal Language: check language with one stack and one queue

Tags: data-structures, stack, queue

**Write a pseudo code of method `isL(w)` which checks if the string `w` is an element of L using only 1 stack and 1 queue**

`L = {a^n⋅b^n⋅c^m⋅d^m | n≥1, m≥1} U {a^n⋅b^m⋅c^m⋅d^n | n≥1, m≥1}`

(a^n is n-th power of a)

You can suppose that stack and queue is already implemented and use them with the variable `stack` and `queue`.

My code answering only half of this question is:

```
isL(w) {

    for (each char ch in w) {
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'c') {
            stack.push( ch );
        }
        else if (ch == 'b' || ch == 'd') {
            queue.enqueue( ch );
        }
        else return false; // no other letter than a,b,c,d
    }

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        if (stack.pop() == 'c' && queue.dequeue()  == 'b')
            continue;
        else if (stack.pop() == 'a' && queue.dequeue() == 'd')
            continue;
        else
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Though I targeted latter subset, it's still wrong for the latter too.

How do I implement the full answer that also checks the former subset?

Answer (score 1):

```
isL(w) {
    if (w[0] != 'a') return false
    stack.push('a')
    for ch in w{
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            if (ch == 'a') stack.push(ch)
            else if (ch == 'b') stack.pop()
            else return false
        } 
        else {
            if (ch == 'c') queue.push(ch)
            else if (!queue.isEmpty() && ch == 'd') queue.dequeue()
            else return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```